# tokenMock.mint is not a function(tokenMock is the deployed Smart Contract)

Tags: erc-20, ethereum-wallet-dapp

[image][image]

I am creating a new Blockchain wallet with ERC20,but during migration,i am getting the error that tokenMock.mint is not a function(tokenMock is the deployed contract)

I am sending the tokens to my account,and then calling the smart Contract with the same account,as it is showing that tokenMock.mint is not a function,so the tokens are not being transferred and hence the balance is 0.

Comment: I am new to the Ethereum world,so it can be a silly error.

Comment: const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");
const DaiTokenMock = artifacts.require("DaiTokenMock");
module.exports = async function(deployer) {
  await deployer.deploy(Migrations);
  await deployer.deploy(DaiTokenMock);
  const tokenMock = await DaiTokenMock.deployed();
  //Mint 1000 dai fro the deployer
  await tokenMock.mint(
    "0x07f073f498fce632f0c177c1c558f0c09e8e0f96",
    "100000000"
  );
};
The migration code,where i am transferring the tokens

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that deployed() will not work until the migrations script has completed, but you have access to deployed address and create an instance pointing to it.

```
module.exports = async function(deployer) {
  await deployer.deploy(Migrations);
  await deployer.deploy(DaiTokenMock);

  const tokenMock = await DaiTokenMock.at(DaiTokenMock.address);

  //Mint 1000 dai fro the deployer
  await tokenMock.mint( "0x07f073f498fce632f0c177c1c558f0c09e8e0f96", "100000000" );
};
```